# How to find all elements bound to a custom event?

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if there is any way to automatically retrieve all elements (or jQuery selectors) that have been bound to a custom events?

In others words, I have bound the following elements to the event "something_added":

```
$('div#slider').bind('something_added',function(){});
$('input#add').bind('something_added',function(){});
```

Anyway to automatically retrieve `$('div#slider')` and `$('input#add')` using the event name ('something_added')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all elements and traverse their collection of events, looking for the event you are interested in :

```
jQuery.each($('#someElementId').data('events'), function(i, event){

    jQuery.each(event, function(i, handler){

        console.log( handler.toString() );

    });

});
```

not sure if it works in jquery 1.8

---

**update:** here is an example I put together : http://jsfiddle.net/nicholmikey/sADZU/5/

```
<html>

    <body>

        <form method="post" action="#">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="return false">           
        </form>
    </body>

</html>​
```

and the jquery (1.7.2):

```
$('input').bind('something_added', function() {});


$.each($('*'), function(i, events) {

    var events = $(this).data('events');
    if (events != null) {
        $.each(events, function(h, event) {
            alert(event[0].type);
    });
}

});
```

Once you find an element that has the event you are looking for, you can use $(this) as it relates to the each($('*')) and do the work you are looking to do

Comment: Definitely won't work in 1.8 unless you move to the new location they're being stored, but even that location isn't guaranteed to exist in the next version.

Comment: That requires you to know the ID of the element. They want to find the elements that have the event bound. Also, when I tried parts of this, `.data('events')` returns a single Object, not an array.

Comment: You can do the selector to select all elements $('*')
I believe the object it returns is a collection that you can traverse, as shown in the example above.